# Firebase how to know specific client is offline?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a device/product using raspberry pi and Firebase...

System flows like this: user buys device on my website and she can use same credentials to login mobile app.

Currently, I am relying on an some how generated uniuqe id put by me in to device to interact to db from device and device to Firebase Realtime Database...

Now I need to know if device is online or offline. Answers should be on possibble two solutions. Because I want to notify user: "Your device is offline"...

**1- on current code(relying on unique id):** if it's possible, how can I achive this.

**2- changing system in to user based:** if I implement this how I must think system. Device will have no display input nor keyboard. For example what happens when user changed her password?

Thank you..

Comment: Cross-posted on https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/311

Comment: @beratuslu Did my answer help?

Comment: @DennisSmolek I am using https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase library so I will need to fork this repo to check if it will work. or do you know any simpler solution?

Comment: Not really, it's 1-3 lines of code so id say it's the simplest I can think of...

Comment: @DennisSmolek I think pyrebase (https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) using Rest API to interact with Firebase. So is it possibble set onDisconnect usindg Rest API?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I think you can use the "Streaming" method and listen to when the stream is cut but I don't use pyrebase so can't speak to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [`onDisconnect`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps)

When your device starts you setup an `onDisconnect` to change its status or even fire a time:

```js
var lastOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref("devices/1234/lastOnline");
lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

var isOnlineRef = firebase.database().ref("devices/1234/isOnline");
isOnlineRef.onDisconnect().set(false);
```

As to the user thing I'm not totally sure I understand. If you isolate your devices with your UID in a path like: `/devices/UID` they exist independently of the users.

For your users you would simply create a list of all of their devices: `/users/UID/devices`

```
{
    1234: 1234,
    5678: 5678
}
```

Then in your app you just first get their list of devices, then create references to them.

In Angular that would look like:

```
// in the ts
public userDevices = this.db.list('/users/UID/devices').valueChanges();

public getDeviceObservable(deviceId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/devices/' + deviceId).valueChanges();
}

//in the template
<div *ngFor="let deviceId of userDevices | async">
    <ng-container *ngIf="getDeviceObservable(deviceId) | async as device">
    {{ device | json }}
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

It's not totally best practice to put a getObservable in the template, you could do it in the component too but thats a whole other talk with switchMap etc.